# C#: Sort DATATABLE with column date

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I know it is a repeated question but i have tried much but i am getting exception

> - $exception  {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}  System.Exception {System.FormatException}

Following is my code please check and guide

**SQL QUERY**

> SELECT gangId as gang, respectPoints as respectPoints,DATE_FORMAT( purchasedDate, '%d-%m-%Y') as date_purchase FROM tbl_gang t where gangId=" + gangId

**Data Access Layer Code**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
cmd.CommandText = inAppPurchaseQuery;
da.Fill(dt)
```

**Sorting Code**

```
dt = gangRPObj.getGangRPLogsBL(gangId, fromDate, toDate);
var sortedTable = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .OrderBy(r => DateTime.ParseExact(("date_purchase"),
                                                "dd-mm-yyyy", null))
             .CopyToDataTable();
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you sort in the database via `ORDER BY purchasedDate`? Also, use parameters instead of string concatenation to prevent sql-injection and date-conversion-issues like this.

Comment: But you passing `date_purchase` as a string, not a variable or something.. Isn't the normal you get `FormatException`?

Comment: Actualy i am filling my datatable with different sources. I mean I have three different tables with similar data. I need to sort this data as a whole

Comment: @TimSchmelter Can you convert the above query with parameters? Actualy just shifted from PHP to C# days ago. Not much familiar with syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing string to datetime conversion that's why exception is coming. Try

```
var orderedRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  let date = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Field<string>("date_purchase"),"dd-mm-yyyy", null)
                  orderby date 
                  select row;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting a date-column as string also doesn't sort correctly. You should also sort in the database instead of in memory and use parameters instead of string concatenation to prevent sql-injection and date-conversion-issues like this.

```
string sql = @"SELECT gangId as gang, 
                      respectPoints as respectPoints, 
                      DATE_FORMAT(purchasedDate, '%d-%m-%Y') as date_purchase,
               FROM tbl_gang t 
               WHERE gangId=@gangId
               ORDER BY purchasedDate ASC";
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
using (var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@gangId", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = gangID;
    da.Fill(dt);  // no need to order this on client side
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for taking out time for this and your suggestions.